# Use grep to find files containing regex patterns

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Is there a way to find all files containing regex patterns? Note, I don't mean grep *using* a regex, I mean finding files that contain a regex string.

i.e., not this:

```
grep -E '\S+\s+\d+' $file
```

but something like:

```
grep -E '<something here>' $file
```

where $file actually contains multiple regex patterns.

UPDATE (for clarification):

I don't want to find THAT pattern (`\S+\s+\d+`), I want to find files with **ANY** regex patterns in them.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149230/discussion-on-question-by-clayton-dukes-use-grep-to-find-files-containing-regex); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The reopening of this question is discussed in meta here: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7149/70524

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you just need to tell `grep` to search with a *string* rather than with a regular expression.

This is what the `-F` option is for:

```
grep -F -- '\S+\s+\d+' "$file"
```

To find all files in the current directory or below it that contains this string (outputs the pathnames of each file that contains a match along with the matching lines):

```
find . -type f -exec grep -F '\S+\s+\d+' /dev/null {} +
```

Or with a `grep` that has `-H` to always print the pathname of the file containing the match:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H -F '\S+\s+\d+' {} +
```

Or, to just find the pathnames of the files (not the matching lines):

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l -F '\S+\s+\d+' {} +
```

To *do* something with those files, use

```sh
find . -type f -exec grep -q -F '\S+\s+\d+' {} \; -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        # code that uses "$pathname" here
    done' sh {} +
```

Note that without knowing more about the files you search in, it's impossible to search for "any regular expression", as any non-empty text string is a regular expression.  If the files we look inside are e.g. JSON files and we know that regular expressions may occur as values of a specific key, then it would be easy to detect the specific files that had this key.

Comment: I was worried that I didn't explain it well (which makes it hard to google for btw). I don't want to find THAT pattern, I want to find files with ANY regex in them.

Comment: @ClaytonDukes you cannot find ANY of free form. you can find only SOME that you know the shape of. any regex expression may include any character the expression itself already uses which makes it hard to detect. yet not without a hope: there are regex syntax highlighters out there to detect some form of them.